# Do calculations in sql query

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck trying to do calculations in sql query.
I have table attendance which looks like this:

```
roll   | class_id | status 
abc    |     1    |   0
qwe    |     1    |   0
zxc    |     2    |   1
xcv    |     1    |   1
mnb    |     2    |   1
poi    |     1    |   1
lkj    |     2    |   0
```

I have to apply formula here:

```
att= (count where roll="abc" status = "1" /  count where roll="abc" status = "1" + count where roll="abc" status = "0") * 100
```

And then show all rolls which have att more than 75 %

```
roll |   att
abc  |   80
xyz  |   100
```

I was doing this calculation after getting values in php. But now I need to get this done in query. I do it individually by

```
select * from attendance where status="0" and roll="abc"
```

and then doing it again for `status="1"`

Can someone explain me ?
How can I approach with the query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` to get a total of the rows that match a condition, because the condition evaluates to `1` when it's true.

```
SELECT roll, ROUND(SUM(status = 1)/COUNT(*) * 100) AS att
FROM attendance
GROUP BY roll
HAVING att > 75
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question.

Comment: I have to count the rows which have status=0 and status=1 instead of sum

Comment: On the rows with 0, `status = 0` returns `1`. When you sum them, that counts those rows.

Comment: Maybe it would be more obvious if I wrote `SUM(IF(status = 0, 1, 0))`. But it's the same thing.

Comment: I've updated the answer so it divides by the count of both statuses.